# How to parse this JSON file in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, database, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a column in a Snowflake table that stores JSON data but the column is of a varchar data type.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{   
    "FLAGS": [],   
    "BANNERS": {},   
    "TOOLS": {     
            "game.appConfig": {       
              "type": [         
                "small",       
                 "normal",        
                  "huge"
              ],      
              "flow": [         
                "control",       
                "noncontrol"
            ]   
        }  
    },   
    "PLATFORM": {} 
}
```

I want to filter only the data inside TOOLS and want to get the following result:

| TOOLS_ID | TOOLS |
| --- | --- |
| game.appConfig | type |
| game.appConfig | flow |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to extract the KEYS as if they were Values? It would probably be easier to transform the json outside of the database. Such as building a schema definition for the Tools element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that the TOOLs can have more than one tool ID, so I wrote this query:

```
with mydata as ( select
'{
    "FLAGS": [],   
    "BANNERS": {},   
    "TOOLS": {     
            "game.appConfig": {       
              "type": [         
                "small",       
                 "normal",        
                  "huge"
              ],      
              "flow": [         
                "control",       
                "noncontrol"
            ]   
        }  
    },   
    "PLATFORM": {} 
}' as v1 )
select main.KEY TOOLS_ID, sub.KEY TOOLS
from mydata,
lateral flatten ( parse_json(v1):"TOOLS" ) main,
lateral flatten ( main.VALUE ) sub;

+----------------+-------+
|    TOOLS_ID    | TOOLS |
+----------------+-------+
| game.appConfig | flow  |
| game.appConfig | type  |
+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column name is C1 and table name T1:

```
select a.t:"TOOLS":"game.appConfig"::string from (select 
parse_json(to_variant(C1))t from T1) a
```